# How can I export ZSH history into JSON?

Tags: zsh, command-history, json

I'd like to export my ZSH history with timestamps as JSON output. How can I achieve this?

Do I need to manually parse the output from something like `history -E`?

Answer (score 0):

Run this in the shell (because `history` is as shell builtin):

```
history -E 0 > history_log.txt
```

And then run the following script:

```
cat history_log.txt | awk '{$1=$2=$3=""}1' | cut -c 4- | jq --raw-input --slurp 'split("\n")' > a_temp.json
cat history_log.txt |awk '{$1=""; print $2, $3}'  | jq --raw-input --slurp 'split("\n")' > b_temp.json

jq 'map( { "command": . } )' a_temp.json > a.json
jq 'map( { "datetime": . } )' b_temp.json > b.json

jq -s 'transpose|map(add)' a.json b.json > output.json
```

The above answer uses awk and jq